# Why does Javascript .filter() not return anything with an active filter (== or ===) but works fine if the boolean logic is of type != or !==?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

```
import React from "react";
import productsData from "./products.js";
import Product from "./Product.js";

function App() {
  const arrrayOfImportedProducts = productsData.map((x) => (
    <Product
      id={x.id}
      name={x.name}
      price={x.price}
      description={x.description}
    />
  ));

  const array2 = arrrayOfImportedProducts.filter((y) => y.id != 1);

  return <div>{array2}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

When I run the code, everything works fine except for the .filter() method. It gives me a blank screen whenever I use == or === to filter a specific element. When I use !== or !=== it shows me all elements of array2 including the ones that shouldn't be in there. Why is it not working?

Comment: React elements don't have an `id` property, hence `y.id` will always return `undefined`. Add a `console.log(y)` to see what values the array contains. You want to filter *before* you render the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're doing your mapping first and your filtering after, your filter function is checking the `.id` property of react elements. React elements don't have an id property. So since the id will never match, your code with `!==` will always pass, and thus everything is included. And the opposite if you use `===`: it will never pass, and so nothing is included.

You will need to switch the order of your code:

```
function App() {
  const filteredProducts = arrrayOfImportedProducts.filter((y) => y.id != 1);
  const arrrayOfImportedProducts = filteredProducts.map((x) => (
    <Product
      id={x.id}
      name={x.name}
      price={x.price}
      description={x.description}
    />
  ));

  return <div>{arrrayOfImportedProducts}</div>;
}
```